# Obtener una palabra a partir de un string en SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, tsql

Tengo un campo varchar que contiene una cadena con lo siguiente:

```
"The Scenario is BUDGET; the Year is 2018; the period is June"
```

Los valores de `Scenario`, `Year` y `Period` pueden variar.

Estoy construyendo un script, y parte de lo que se necesita es obtener la ultima palabra antes de cada punto y coma (En este caso `BUDGET` y `2018`, pero podrían ser otras palabras) y la ultima palabra (en este caso el mes).

He hecho varias pruebas y lo mas que he logrado es lo siguiente:

```
select SUBSTRING(strDescription, CHARINDEX('The Scenario is', 
strDescription,+16), CHARINDEX(';',strDescription,-1)) as Scenario,
,SUBSTRING(strDescription, CHARINDEX('The Year is', strDescription), 
CHARINDEX(';',strDescription,1)) as Year
,SUBSTRING(strDescription, CHARINDEX('The Start Period is', strDescription), 
CHARINDEX(';',strDescription,-1)) as Period
from TECHBUD_TASK_AUDIT;


Resultado:
----------------------    ----------------------    ----------------------
The Scenario is BUDGET    the Year is 2018; the S   the Start Period is Jun

Resultado esperado:
--------   --------    -------
BUDGET     2018      June
```

Probe varias sugerencias de ustedes, como el REVERSE y el LEFT, pero no logro hacer la sintaxis correcta. Hay alguna manera de lograr armar la sentencia sin el uso de variables?

Gracias!!
Kyana

Comment: ¿Todo los registros tienen un *;* (punto y coma) en tu tabla `TECHBUD_TASK_AUDIT`?

Comment: Hola Davlio, Si, todos lo tienen, ese es el punto de referencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta no tiene porque ser complicada, basta con primero obtener lo que está hasta antes del `;`, luego, hacer una reversa a esa cadena para quitar lo que está después del espacio, y por último, regresar la cadena a su estado original recortada.

Tomando como ejemplo el siguiente código te podrás dar cuenta:

```
DECLARE @cadena VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @cadena_pivote VARCHAR(64)
SET @cadena = 'The Scenario is BUDGET; the Year is 2018'

SET @cadena_pivote = REPLACE(@cadena, SUBSTRING(@cadena, CHARINDEX(';', @cadena), LEN(@cadena)), '')

SELECT @cadena_pivote ----> Resultado: The Scenario is BUDGET

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@cadena_pivote), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@cadena_pivote))-1))
----> Resultado: BUDGET
```

Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración y sus resultados](http://rextester.com/TAGZ19411)</kbd>

Comment: Hola! Gracias voy a probar con este script. El problema es que no puedo setear 'The Scenario is BUDGET; the Year is 2018' porque son diferentes escenarios (BUDGET, PLAN, etc). En este caso necesitaria setear el campo.

Comment: @Kyana.cs bueno, sin importar la palabra o escenario que sea, comentas que siempre requieres la palabra que está antes del `;`, y ya con eso que puse la puedes obtener. Si requieres algo más completo edita tu pregunta para saber qué más podemos hacer ;)

Comment: adaptando `SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@cadena_pivote), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@cadena_pivote))-1))` pude obtener la palabra `BUDGET` Sin embargo, trato de hacer lo mismo para obtener el año (2018) y no me funciona. Y la verdad no entiendo, porque estoy buscando todo de la misma manera. El codigo que funciona es: `SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strDescription, CHARINDEX('the Year is', strDescription), CHARINDEX(';',strDescription))), CHARINDEX (' ', REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strDescription, CHARINDEX('the Year is', strDescription), CHARINDEX(';',strDescription))))))
FROM TECHBUD_TASK_AUDIT;`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que la sintaxis **SUBSTRING** funciona de la siguiente forma:

```
SUBSTRING ( expresion, comienzo, longitud)
```

Donde:

- Expresión es la cadena de caracteres de la que se desea extraer caracteres
- Comienzo es la expresión entera que especifica desde donde va a empezar el conjunto de caracteres retornados.
- Longitud como su nombre lo indica, cuantos caracteres deseas retornar a partir del **comienzo**.

Si sabes la longitud de la palabra a buscar te serviría.

Ahora de no ser así puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
USE[my_db]
SELECT SUBSTRING(strDescription, 22, CHARINDEX(';', strDescription)-22)
FROM TECHBUD_TASK_AUDI
```

Con ello le dices al substring que empieze en la posicion 22 (la cual asumo es siempre la misma, de no ser así no funcionará correctamente) y en la longitud le especifico una resta entre la ubicación del caracter (';') y los 22 que ya tienes considerados, lo cual te traería la palabra que se encuentra justo antes de ese caracter determinado. Espero te haya servido mi solución, saludos.

Comment: Gracias Rostan :) Lo hice tal cual tu sintanxis pero no funcionó: SELECT SUBSTRING(strDescription, 22, CHARINDEX(';', strDescription)-22)
from TECHBUD_TASK_AUDI ----ERROR: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'TECHBUD_TASK_AUDI'. Probe cambiando algunos parentesis pero solo logre traer:  "BUDGET; the Year is 20"

Comment: ok, pero el error que tienes es referente a la tabla TECHBUD_TASK_AUDI , no a la sintaxis usada, verifica que estas en la base correcta, ya que el error dice que no existe el objeto "TECHBUD_TASK_AUDI " y me parece que es por que en vez de apuntar a tu base, estás quizás en el master.

Comment: Edite la pregunta para que no tengas que cambiar algo en la sintaxis, solo fíjate en el USE[my_db], asegurate que en vez de my_db esté el nombre de tu base de datos.

Comment: Rostan, tienes razon, no me habia dado cuenta que la tabla estaba mal escrita.Lo ejecute correctamente pero no me trae solamente la palabra BUDGET, sigue trayendo lo que aparece despues.

Comment: No estas omitiendo la resta del CHARINDEX - 22 verdad?! esa es la clave para extraer la palabra antes del ";".

Comment: Estoy usando todo, he jugado con los numeros pero sigue trayendo las otras palabras

Answer (score 0):

Estos son los ejemplos dónde uno extraña las expresiones regulares. Resolver tu problema implica que uno deba buscar ciertos caracteres empezando desde la izquierda en algunos casos y desde el final en otros, por ejemplo: el `;` es fácil de ubicar, ahora el espacio anterior no lo podemos calcular de la misma forma por que nos identificaría alguno anterior, lo ideal es "dar vuelta" el texto y recién ahí contar. Para esto hacemos uso de  [`REVERSE()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/reverse-transact-sql), luego simplemente es ajustar el cálculo con esos dos números:

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo  VARCHAR(255)

SELECT  @Ejemplo = 'The Scenario is BUDGET; the Year is 2018'

SELECT  @Ejemplo,
    SUBSTRING(@Ejemplo, 
                CHARINDEX(';', @Ejemplo) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Ejemplo, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @Ejemplo)))) + 2,
                CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@Ejemplo, 1, CHARINDEX(';', @Ejemplo)))) - 2
    ),
    SUBSTRING(@Ejemplo, 
            LEN(@Ejemplo)-CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@Ejemplo)) + 2 , 
            LEN(@Ejemplo)
    )
```

La salida:

```
======================================== ====== ====
The Scenario is BUDGET; the Year is 2018 BUDGET 2018
```

Nota: Es conveniente hacer un `RTRIM()` previamente a la cadena a analizar ya que un caso dónde exista un espacio luego del año va  a fallar.

Comment: Hola! Gracias voy a probar con este script. El problema es que no puedo setear 'The Scenario is BUDGET; the Year is 2018' porque son diferentes escenarios (BUDGET, PLAN, etc). En este caso necesitaria setear el campo.

Comment: Lo que te pase es un ejemplo, para incorporarlo en tu consulta, debes reemplazar `@Ejemplo` por el nombre del campo. Saludos